# Is there a 120 film with cool colors?

Tags: film, color, white-balance, film-cameras

Does anyone know of some 120 film models that yield cool colors? I'm not looking for super saturated films or weird toy films by Lomography. I'm looking for very cinematic colors. Most likely vintage. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you been shooting so far?

Comment: Are you using the word "cool" to describe colors nearer the blue end than the red end of the spectrum? Or are you using the word "cool" to indicate you want something that looks "hip" or "groovy"?

Comment: Lol @MichaelClark groovy

Answer (score 3):

The really muted cinema stuff—like Saving Private Ryan—isn't about the film, it's about the processing.

Specifically, bleach bypass. In color film developed normally, activating the color couplers is a side-effect of developing three b&w silver images. These silver images are then bleached away, leaving just the color. In bleach bypass that step is omitted and the b&w images coexists with the color image.

Don't know of anyone doing it commercially for still-camera size runs. Doing E-6 and C-41 at home isn't rocket science but it's not nearly as simple nor forgiving as traditional b&w. Temperature control in particular needs to be dead-on for repeatable/predictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Fuji is more muted and cooler than Kodak. I've read that there was some AGFA slide film around in the beginning of 2000s, known for it's 70s color palette, but probably you won't be able to get those anymore.
How does Fuji Pro 400H look to you?
https://www.flickr.com/groups/1084764@N20/pool/ 
(keep in mind that there is postprocessing involved)